# Wicket and Guice, injection in the webpage, and testabilitiy

Tags: unit-testing, wicket, guice

I've been trying to get wicket and guice working together, more specifically injecting a facade (or a controller, whatever) into the webpage, with guice. The problem seems to be that I cannot do any other injection than field injection, in the webpage. If I try to use setter injection, the setter just doesn't get called. Constructor injection into the webpage doesn't seem to be possible (or I didn't find how).

So, I seem to be left with field injection as the only possibility when injecting in the webpage.

Can anybody, first of all, confirm that this is correct? I seem to have found on the site of apache that setter injection doesn't work as of wicket 1.5 (I'm on 6 by the way) but haven't found any more information about it.

Secondly, if, indeed, it's only possible to do field injection in the webpage, how can I cleanly unit test field injection with guice? (I'm thinking about a mock test, all I need to know is that the facade in question is correctly called with the correct arguments after pressing a button, the facade itself can be tested in another unit test).

Didn't supply any code, because the question seems to be rather basic. If needs be, I'll put in some snippets

Kasper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had been struggling with this too. The integration ended up really smooth:

http://software.danielwatrous.com/wicket-guice-including-unittests/

Following this method the injector is injected, which gives full flexibility.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. I didn't inject the injector in my pages though, only in the WicketApplicatino. Just used the inject annotation in the pages because I think that's nicer. Like that, I don't need to inject the Injector in the pages, just in the wicket application to be able to test it. Just create my own inline module in the test set up to make it very explicit and create the tester like that. Like your article by the way.

Answer (score 0):

For all I know, wicket IoC module only provide field inject for components, so there is no easy way to inject something to a compoment from setter. You can confirm this by reading Wicket-IoC/Wicket-Guice source code.

To clear an injected field, you can use Java reflation API to make it's field `null`. However, Page might have some state after a test. So I would recommend simply recreate page after each test.

Comment: Alright, I didn't bother reading the code but I quickly tried out field and setter injection with a wicket webpage and a non wicket component in the same project, and indeed, it seems that setter injection in web pages is not supported. I used the PrivateAccessor class to inject a mock, but it hurts my eyes a little. I'll start reading the code one of these moments to find out the reason behind this, because it annoys me a little.

Answer (score 0):

I use Wicket with Guice doing mocked test. You can see how I bind everything here http://blog.yanivkessler.com/2010/05/wicket-and-guice-alternate-route.html (with my comment under Gaetan)

Tests are not a problem since the injection is done by the Component constructor. In my case, I have small tests on Component that check the calls on mocked services depending on user interactions.

Here a simplified version of the initialization of my tests.

```
  @BeforeClass
  public void buildMockedTester() {
    List<Module> modules = buildModules();
    injector = Guice.createInjector(modules);
    MyApplicationFactory instance = injector.getInstance(MyApplicationFactory.class);
    WebApplication application = instance.buildWebApplication();
    tester = new WicketTester(application);
}
```

Comment: I have been thinking along those lines as well, but that implies having the dependency injection framework right there in my unit tests, which is a bit messy as well. If it would have been in the integration tests, I could live with it. On the other hand, it might be more readable than my private field injection thingy right now. I'll sleep on it I think. Anyways, it would have been nicer if we could have used setter injection...

Comment: I have a very efficient test configuration, only with mocks. If you want to manually set your fields for tests, make their access "package". I don't find setter injection a good thing with wicket as you usually initialize your components during the construction phase.

Comment: Well, you're right about the setter injection thing, ctor injection is the best, but that's apparently not available for webpages, field injection on the other hand is not the way to go according to me, and the package private thing is something I prefer to avoid, because it's compromising design to be able to test. Anyhow, I think I'm warming towards your solution, it seems to be the cleanest achievable. Still think it's a pity to have guice dependencies in pure unit tests, but it's more refactor-proof than the PrivateAccessor solution I have now, and if it's fast enough it's okay I guess.